# Python getopt taking second option as argument of first option

Tags: python, getopt

I am trying to use `getopts`for command line parsing. However, if I set the options to have mandatory arguments via `:`or `=` and no argument is given in the command line, the following option is taken as an argument of the first option. I would like this to raise an error instead. How can this be resolved?

Working example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, getopt, warnings


argv = sys.argv

try:
  opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv[1:], "c:", ["config-file=", "sample-list="])
  print >> sys.stderr, opts

except getopt.GetoptError as msg:
  print msg
```

Running this script on the command line like this:

```
python getopt_test.py --config-file --sample-list
```

results in the following output (`opts`):

```
[('--config-file', '--sample-list')]
```

Comment: use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) instead of getopt, as said in the documentation of [getopt](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/getopt.html): *Users who are unfamiliar with the C getopt() function or who would like to write less code and get better help and error messages should consider using the argparse module instead.*

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong while running :

```
 python getopt_test.py --config-file --sample-list
```

In your snippet:

```
 opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv[1:], "c:", ["config-file=", "sample-list="])

 # config-file requires argument i.e what ever argument come next in sys.argv list
 # sample-list requires argument i.e what ever argument come next in sys.argv list
```

So, when you run as `python getopt_test.py --config-file --sample-list`,

**--sample-list** is just an argument to **--config-file**.

Lets confirm it by printing `opts`, which is list of tuple element containing first element inside tuple as the option name and second element as the arguments.

```
tmp/: python get.py --config-file --sample-list
[('--config-file', '--sample-list')] []
tmp/:

# lets put a proper argument for config-file
tmp/: python get.py --config-file 'argument_for_config_file'
[('--config-file', 'argument_for_config_file')] []
tmp/:

# Lets run with proper sample-list
tmp/: python get.py --config-file 'argument_for_config_file' --sample-list 'here is the 
list'
[('--config-file', 'argument_for_config_file'), ('--sample-list', 'here is the list')]   
[]
tmp/:
```

So, you need to write your own proper parse to make sure the user is providing the right options and argument. IF you are using optparse.

**About the Exception: exception getopt.GetoptError**

**This is raised when an unrecognized option is found in the argument list or when an option
 requiring an argument is given none.** But in your case nothing of the rules was violate, thats why it was running silently without any error.

To prevent from all this **optparse pitfall**: highly recommend to use [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) which has tons of new and good feature to solve all your problem.

Comment: So, there is no way to make getopt recognize that things that start with "--" are not supposed to be arguments to an option and, therefore, raise an error because no argument was given?

Comment: if you wanna more detail how getopt parse sys.argv please check here http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/getopt.py#l144